# I have ALB and internet gateway for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have ALB and internet gateway for Lambda.

For `lambda` https access works automatically.

For `ALB` I can't access https.

I am not still sure though,,

I need to use `ACM` for `ALB`?, and don't need to do anything for lambda gateway??

Am I correct? and why this difference happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda https access, your client's https is validated against the Amazon domain, and thus uses the Amazon certificates.

ALB https access, your client's https is validated against the domain which you specify, and therefore you must provide a certificate for that; ACM is used to store your certificate.

Comment: Thank you !! Ah I understand.As you mentioned, I don't need to use my domain for lambda but need for ALB